# In C++, can I safely initialize an unordered_map with values from different files?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, static-order-fiasco

Imagine code like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<Foo *()>> FooFactory;
void registerFoo(std::string name, std::function<Foo *()> factory)
{
    FooFactory.emplace(name, factory);
}
```

If I now would write code like this in another file:

```
static bool Baz = [](){ registerFoo("baz", []() { return new BazFoo(); })}();
```

And yet another:

```
static bool Bar = [](){ registerFoo("bar", []() { return new BarFoo(); })}();
```

In this case registerFoo is called as the program initializes, but FooFactory is then zeroed out, so the registered functions disappear.

Is there a way to make this work in a safe, compiler-independent way (for c++14)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could stick the factory itself inside of a function:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<Foo *()>>& getFactory() {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<Foo *()>> FooFactory;
    return FooFactory;
}
```

Which your registration function can go through:

```
void registerFoo(std::string name, std::function<Foo *()> factory)
{
    getFactory().emplace(name, factory);
}
```

This should guarantee ordering.

Comment: This is what I do.  I also sometimes make it a `boost::` or `std::optional<blah>&` that by default is constructed with a `blah`, because that permits me to destroy such singletons in the order I choose, instead of in compiler-determined per-runtime reverse order of construction.

Comment: I note the solution of VTT above uses a dynamically allocated object instead. Is there any advantage to that?

Comment: The typical justification for using dynamic allocation or similar hackery is to make the object available during destruction of global objects as well. May or may not be an actual problem, depending on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Although using a global context like this is not encouraged, here are some more items you should consider in addition to @Barry's answer:

1. You should guard the `emplace` with a `mutex` (in case multiple threads try to add to the `unordered_map`)
2. Optionally return the success argument of emplace (accessed by `second`).
3. Forward your arguments to ensure perfect forwarding:

```cpp
bool registerFoo(std::string &&name, std::function<Foo *()> &&factory)
{
    static std::mutex register_mutex;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(register_mutex);

    return getFactory().emplace(
            std::forward<std::string>(name),
            std::forward<std::std::function<Foo *()>>(factory)
        ).second;
}
```

and then:

```cpp
static bool Baz = [](){ return registerFoo("baz", []() { return new BazFoo(); })}();
```

Don't forget to make a facility to delete all these free function pointers when you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

First, you want some thread safety:

```
template<class T, class M=std::shared_timed_mutex> // shared_mutex in C++17
struct mutex_guarded {
  template<class F>
  auto write( F&& f )
  ->std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<F(T&)>> {
    auto l = lock();
    return std::forward<F>(f)(t);
  }
  template<class F>
  auto read( F&& f ) const
  ->std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<F(T const&)>> {
    auto l = lock();
    return std::forward<F>(f)(t);
  }
  mutex_guarded() {}
  template<class T0, class...Ts,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T0>, mutex_guarded>{},int> =0
  >
  mutex_guarded(T0&& t0, Ts&&...ts):
    t(std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
  {}
  mutex_guarded( mutex_guarded const& o ):
    t(o.copy_from())
  {}
  mutex_guarded( mutex_guarded && o ):
    t(o.move_from())
  {}
  mutex_guarded& operator=(mutex_guarded const&)=delete;
  mutex_guarded& operator=(mutex_guarded &&)=delete;
  mutex_guarded& operator=(T const& t) {
    write([&t](T& dest){dest=t;});
    return *this;
  }
  mutex_guarded& operator=(T&& t) {
    write([&t](T& dest){dest=std::move(t);});
    return *this;
  }
private:
  T copy_from() const& { return read( [](T const& t){ return t; } ); }
  T copy_from() && { return move_from(); }
  T move_from() { return write( [](T& t){ return std::move(t); } ); }

  std::unique_lock<M> lock() const {
    return std::unique_lock<M>(m);
  }
  std::shared_lock<M> lock() {
    return std::shared_lock<M>(m);
  }
   M m; // mutex
   T t;
};
```

which lets us have a:

```
using foo_factory = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Foo>()>;
using foo_factories = std::unordered_map<std::string, foo_factory>;
mutex_guarded<foo_factories>& get_foo_factories() {
  static mutex_guarded<foo_factories> map;
  return map;
}
```

which has thread-safe initialization, then

```
void registerFoo(std::string name, std::function<Foo *()> factory)
{
  get_foo_factories().write([](auto& f){f.emplace(name, factory);});
}
```

is thread safe and guarantees initialization of the factories early enough.

At shutdown, the timing of the destruction of the factories is both beyond your control (reverse order of construction) and may be too early.

```
mutex_guarded<foo_factories>*& get_foo_factories() {
  static auto* map = new mutex_guarded<foo_factories>;
  return map;
}
void registerFoo(std::string name, std::function<Foo *()> factory)
{
  get_foo_factories()->write([](auto& f){f.emplace(name, factory);});
}
void end_foo_factories() {
  auto*& ptr = get_foo_factories();
  delete ptr; ptr = nullptr;
}
```

this will place it on the heap where it is going to live a bit longer.  Note this also leaks both the factories and the map; manual destruction "late enough" can be added.  Note that this destruction is not thread safe, nor can it cheaply be made thread safe; it should occur after all threads have been cleaned up.

Comment: If the registerFunctions are called only during static initialization, it is thread safe and guaranteed by standard.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid static initialization order fiasco you can wrap up factory access into function call constructing it during first call:

```
using
t_NameToFactoryMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<Foo *()>>

t_NameToFactoryMap * p_foo_factory{}; // initialized with nullptr before dynamic initialization starts

t_NameToFactoryMap &
getFooFactory(void)
{
    if(!p_foo_factory)
    {
        p_foo_factory = new t_NameToFactoryMap{};
    }
    return(*p_foo_factory);
}

void registerFoo(std::string name, std::function<Foo *()> factory)
{
    getFooFactory().emplace(name, factory);
}
```

The drawback of such autoregistration methods is that they will create problems if you decide to utilize them in some static library project. Projects using this static library won't reference `Baz` or `Bar` unless they link this static library using some compiler-dependent flag, such as `--whole-archive` for gcc.

So a better solution would be to explicitly create factory below `main` and register all the required items without dealing with dynamic initialization at all.

Comment: I like the idea but I dislike the implementation.  You have a `new` without a `delete` and while it shouldn't be a problem it is still unsightly.  If your always going to have to call `getFooFactory()` you might as well make the map a static variable inside the function and that gets rid of the pointer, `new`, and having to do your own initialization check.

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree that this is rather sketchy solution that just makes autoregistration work regardless of initialization order. However the important part is that autoregistration still won't work when used inside of static library without compiler-specific magic.

Comment: This isn't thread safe.  Use a magic static for thread safety here, even if you use a pointer and dynamic allocation.